# Get a bash script to run node.js

Tags: node.js, bash

I have a node.js file that accepts an integer arg.

I'm trying to write a bash script that looks for number of available cores and launches main.js for each available core.

For 1 core it should call:

```
node main.js 3000 &
```

For 2 cores:

```
node main.js 3000 &
node main.js 30001 &
```

And so on...

This is my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
numCores=`getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN`
i=0
j=3000
while [ $i < $numCores ]
do
    j=$($j+$i)
    node /myApp/main.js $j &
    i=$($i+1)
done
```

When I try to run it, I get this error:

```
bash launchnode.sh
launchnode.sh: line 5: 2: No such file or directory
```

main.js and launchnode.sh are in the same directory.

Any help?

Comment: http://shellcheck.net/ would have caught this (and a bunch of other bugs) for you automatically.

Comment: j=$(($j+$i))   double the parentheses for arithmetic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is here:

```
while [ $i < $numCores ]
```

In bash `<` is for input redirection. `[` is an alias for the `test` command, and `test 0 < 2` means "send input from the file named `2` to the command `test 0`.

Instead, use `test`'s `-lt` option for a less-than comparison. Also, don't forget to quote your variables:

```
while [ "$i" -lt "$numCores" ]
```

Or, if you're only targeting bash, you can use arithmetic expansion:

```
while (( i < numCores ))
```

You also need to use double parentheses on subsequent lines for arithmetic:

```
i=$(($j+$i))
```

Comment: One problem -- not the only problem. `while (( i < numCores ))` might be an easier-to-read version if we're only targeting bash, btw. Inside `[ ]` you should really be quoting your expansions, by the way -- `[ "$i" -lt "$numCores" ]`; that way if we somehow get an unset variable we have an error that describes that accurately.

Comment: Actually, I'd suggest `for (( port=3000; port < (3000 + numCores); port++)); do node /myApp/main.js "$port" & done`. All the math's inside the C-style `for` loop's condition, including initialization, comparison and increment.

Comment: Good catch @CharlesDuffy. Thanks.